# How to save a string from a Telerik RadWatermarkTextbox

Tags: xaml, telerik

I have this line of code in my `Setup.xaml` file:
`<telerik:RadWatermarkTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="IMAPServer" WatermarkContent="user.example.com"/>`.
When the user clicks on the box they can type the server they're using into it, but I'd like to be able to save the text in this box when they press a button to go to the next page, so I can save the server in a .JSON file. How do I do this? Do I need to create a function in my `Setup.xaml.cs` and call it in `Setup.xaml`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that telerik TextBox but for a regular TextBox, you can bind the Text like so:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

Then in your viewmodel class, you have the text saved to the "PropertyOnViewModel" property, which is a string.